# Oauth2RestTemplate - not reading certificates from custom truststore

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

By default, Oauth2RestTemplate is reading certificates from jre truststore. But when we configure the template with HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory, it is not reading the certificates from the custom truststore.
Below is the code:

```
@Configuration
public class OauthConfig {

@Resource
private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory backendHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;

@Resource
private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager backendPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;

@Value("${keystore.path}")
private File certificatePath;

@Value("${keystore.password}")
private String certificatePassword;


@Bean("testOauthRestTemplate")
public OAuth2RestOperations oauth2RestTemplate() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException

{
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setClientId("clientId");
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret("12345");
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("https://test:8080/oauth/token");
    resourceDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
    resourceDetails.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
    AccessTokenRequest request = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();

    OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(request));

    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    HttpClient httpClient = null;


    httpClient = clientBuilder.setConnectionManager(backendPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
            .setSSLSocketFactory(SslSettings.sslConnectionSocketFactory(certificatePath, certificatePassword))
            .disableCookieManagement().build();


    backendHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    oauth2RestTemplate.setRequestFactory(backendHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory);

    return oauth2RestTemplate;
}

@Bean("backendHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory")
public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory backendHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
}


@Bean("backendPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager")
public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager backendPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager() throws KeyManagementException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {

    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("https", SslSettings.sslConnectionSocketFactory(certificatePath, certificatePassword))
            .build();


    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = 
            new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
            socketFactoryRegistry);
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(200);

    return poolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
}

}
```

Below is the Exception:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
                at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
                at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
                at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
                at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
                at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
                at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
                at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
                at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
                at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:723)
                ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
                at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
                at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
                at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
                at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
                at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
                at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
                ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
                at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
                at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
                at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
                ... 93 common frames omitted
```

Need some suggestion/help..Not able to find the solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently accepted answer gives a solution with incorrect reasoning. The error is not because your OAuth2RestTemplate is unable to access the certificate stores, but it is because the AccessTokenProvider on the OAuth2RestTemplate creates its own RestTemplate internally in order to request the token. In order to set the provider for that internal RestTemplate, you can do the below (change to different types of AccessTokenProviders based on what kind of OAuth you're doing)

```
ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider provider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();
provider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(provider);
```

The accepted answer works by applying the trustStore to all requests, which isn't always what you want to do, as it's almost always better to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Your manually configured `HttpClient` seems not to be able to access the `TLS` certificate stores. The given error message (`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: ...`) points out that a valid SSL-connection couldn't be established, because the program is not able to find the path to the certificate stores.

To solve this issue, you can try to set the `Java` keystore and truststore settings like this:

**SSLConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SSLConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    private void configureSSL() {
      //load the 'javax.net.ssl.trustStore' and
      //'javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword' from application.properties
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", env.getProperty("server.ssl.trust-store")); 
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",env.getProperty("server.ssl.trust-store-password"));
    }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
server.ssl.trust-store: YOUR_TRUST_STORE_PATH
server.ssl.trust-store-password: YOUR_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD
```